# how to receive/send multiple iOS push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented push notifications in my application and receiving them without any issue. Problem occurs when my app is in offline, if I send more than one notification at that time (eg.5 notifications), when my device comes to online it is receiving only the latest notification.
Even when I checked with the apple documentation it is clearly mentioned that APNS will retain only the latest push notification received from 3rd party server.
But how all the other apps like(social networking and chat apps) could able to send multiple notifications when device goes to online from offline.

Do we have to implement specifically or we have any 3rd party providers or frameworks which gives the service.

If any 3rd party providers are giving the service, how they are doing? does apple gives any feedback server whether the notification is delivered to the device or not so that our 3rd party server can send the undelivered message again?

Comment: Your app should check for new data on the server when it starts and/or receives a push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this by external services which gives you several advantages:

1) send push notifications asynchronouslly
2) send multiple push notifications
3) easilly subscribe unsubscribe

I have used **Urban Airship** and have been sutisfied.

Comment: does it manages and pushes the offline notifications (multiple notifications sent when the device is in offline) when user comes online.

Comment: Yes, it does. You can try this by fast tutorial: https://docs.urbanairship.com/engage/getting-started/